# C# MediaPlayer causing InvalidDeploymentException

Tags: c#, exception

I have a program that plays a `MediaPlayer` sound then a different `MediaPlayer` song in the background. When I cancel the action and play the first `MediaPlayer` sound everything is fine. But from here on whenever I try to access that same sound again from `MediaPlayer.Open` I get a `InvalidDeploymentException` that my program fails to catch.

```
playerCry = new MediaPlayer();
playerCry.MediaEnded += OnMediaEnded;
playerCry.Volume = PokeManager.Settings.MutedVolume;
playerMusic = new MediaPlayer();
playerMusic.MediaEnded += OnMediaEnded;
playerMusic.Volume = PokeManager.Settings.MutedVolume;

string cryFile = PokemonDatabase.FindCryFile(pokemon.DexID);
try {
    if (cryFile != null)
        playerCry.Open(new Uri(cryFile));
    else
        playerCry = null;
} catch (Exception) {
    playerCry = null;
}
playerMusic.Open(new Uri(System.IO.Path.Combine(PokeManager.ApplicationDirectory, "Resources", "Audio", "Evolution.wav")));
```

Why is MediaPlayer throwing this exception and how can I fix it.